# Programmatically sign in to google account using google workspace domain

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-java-client

We are trying to implement the user authentication/authorization using google as IDP. The requirement is user lands on our web app login page and type their google account emial/ password. We will take this creds and authenticate user and then programmatically using api's sign in this user to their google account behind the seens and then let them access all the allowed apps(google apps)/third party apps.The users here are coming through our enterprise customer who are using google as their IDP and we want to make use of existing IDP setup. The similar is possible through Okta api letting user login to their okta account through api's behind the scene for accessing all okta apps.Not getting any documentation for implementing this with google auth.The google sign in with GIS needs a active browser session to let user give consent to sign in with google account. Any documentation would be helpful here. User consent screen is ok to have but we want to sign in to account through api's and not with active user session on user's browser.

Comment: So you are *storing* their google credentials? That sounds a bit sketchy. Defintely not the way GIS is designed. The intended experience is active user session login, look at the Code Model for guidance on getting access & refresh tokens.

Comment: Not storing the credentials, that just temporary until user is authenticated that it's a right google account user. With current OAuth implementation, it takes to consent page for user to give consent. Want to skip this consent part.The idea is the just check the user landing on this page is a google account user for that customer domain.

Comment: Code might help. How do you know this is the right account user for the customer domain? You can use google sign in to obtain the basic end-user info without granting them access to anything. In that scenario, they would land on the app login page, and instead of typing in any passwords, they would simply use google sign in (and often will not need to enter their password to do so). If they sign in to your app, you can obtain the user's basic info from google in order to make whatever secondary decisions you need to make. 

Like I say: code might help understand your intention.

Comment: Well was first going through all the available google api's documentation to start on the POC.All the google authentication api's mention the consent page. All I need is to make a auth call to google api's and if that returns 200 that user email password is correct we need to let the user in. We need to make sure the user name password is correct.